# The difference between feature importance and feature weights in XGBoost

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, xgboost, xgbclassifier

I am trying to analyze the output of running xgb classifier. I haven't been able to find a proper explanation of the difference between the feature weights and the features importance chart.
Here is a sample screenshot (not from my dataset but the same analysis I am running).
I will appreciate explanations or references to where I can get any.
Thanks in advance
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjVh8.png)

Comment: Check out https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/65973/differences-between-feature-weighting-and-feature-selection

Comment: "Feature importance is like feature weighting" :) Would love to find out a bit more about the difference

Comment: Feature weights is something that theoretically can also be set manually for adjusting the training. Although an API is not always provided to do it.